# Correct way to write setup script for setuptools? Can't find the error

Tags: python, setuptools, trac

For my Trac plugin, I want to pack my scripts and data together as an egg file. I used multiple different examples I found online as reference, but my egg file was not recognized by Trac.

I looked inside the egg file with 7zip, and all of the files seem to be in there, so I think it might be a problem with the meta data.
The plugin itself works if I use just the .py script or an egg-link with absolute paths.

My project structure looks like this:

```
ticket-printer-plugin (the project root)
    |
    ---setup.py
    ---ticketprinter
        |
        ---__init__.py
        ---ticketprinter_admin.py
        ---ticketprinter_export.py
        ---htdocs
            |
            ---css
            |   |
            |   ---ticketformat.css
            |
            ---templates
                |
                ---admin_panel.html
```

The init file in the ticketprinter package contains the following:

```
from ticketprinter_export import *
from ticketprinter_admin import *
```

The setup.py script looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='TracTicketPrinter', version='0.1',
    packages=['ticketprinter'],
    package_data={'ticketprinter': [
        'htdocs/css/*.css',
        'htdocs/templates/*.html']},
    entry_points={
        'trac.plugins': [
            'ticketprinter = ticketprinter',
        ],
    },
)
```

I checked the logs and there were no errors. It looks like Trac doesn't even recognize the egg file, so it might be a problem with the paths or the dependencies, but I can't find the mistake.

Comment: It looks perfect to me python - wise,  so it must be an issue with Trac.  Do they recommend setuptools?

Comment: It's the standard way for multi file Trac plugins.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this could be an issue with the `*` star import in `__init__.py` and the entry point. Did you try explicitly specifying the dotted name to the module(s) that contain classes implementing a `Component`? Like `'ticketprinter_export = ticketprinter.ticketprinter_export'`?

Comment: Also note that when you make changes to your entry points, you need to rebuild the `.egg-info`, for example by re-running `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: @LukasGraf I tried that, too. It also doesn't work. I'm curious why the egg-link works, but the egg file doesn't.

Comment: Where are you locating the egg when you install it? Are you installing to your site-packages directory using `python setup.py install`? Or are you building the egg using `python setup.py bdist_egg` and copying the egg from the `dist` directory to Trac's `plugins` directory?

Comment: I recommend following the advice of @LukasGraf, using `['ticketprinter_export = ticketprinter.ticketprinter_export', 'ticketprinter_admin = ticketprinter.ticketprinter_admin']`.

Comment: That was the problem, it works now.